# Comentarios de codigo en VS code

Tags: vscode

Queria preguntar si alguien sabe como cambiar el atajo de teclado para los comentarios de codigo en VS code porque el de `Ctrl` + `/` no me funciona devido a que tengo un teclado español y la `/` esta dentro de la tecla del 7 o si hay otro atajo predeterminado

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> en windows o bien <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> para Mac

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar la configuración dirigite a pestaña superior donde dice:

`File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`

o si esta en español

`Archivo > Preferencias > Atajos del Teclado`

o usa la combinación de teclas

`ctrl + k + s`

Esto te abrirá una ventana donde vienen todas las combinaciones de teclas y el atajo que tienen asignado, en tu caso debes de buscar el atajo que dice `add line commnet` o `agregar comentario de linea` como se muestra en la imagen de a continuación:

[image: editar combinacion de teclas de atajos vscode]

Ya por ultimo has doble clic sobre el atajo que quieres editar, se abrirá un cuadro de dialogo donde debes escribir la nueva combinación de teclas (presiona la combinación de teclas que quieres usar) y cuando termines presiona `ENTER`, ya con eso debe quedar guardada la nueva configuración.